# C++ Reading memory address

Tags: visual-c++

I simply want to read value of an address in memory.

This is my simple target program.

```
class Target
{
public:
    void Function()
    {
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
    }
private:
    const char* str = "Hi";
};

Target* g_pTarget;

void main()
{
    Target target;
    g_pTarget = &target;

    while ( true )
    {
        if ( GetAsyncKeyState(VK_NUMPAD1) & 1 )
        {
            g_pTarget->Function();
        }
    }
}
```

I found address of string pointer using debugger
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MvKF.png)

and this is how I read address value

```
DWORD WINAPI Main_Thread(LPVOID param)
{
    unsigned long long PID  = GetPID("target.exe");
    MODULEENTRY32 module    = GetModule("target.exe", PID);
    HANDLE phandle          = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, PID);

    while ( !GetAsyncKeyState(VK_END) )
    {
        if ( GetAsyncKeyState(VK_NUMPAD3) )
        {
            char *result[256];

            ReadProcessMemory(phandle, (void*) ( ( char )module.modBaseAddr + 0x109B30 ), &result, sizeof(result), 0);
            
            printf("Address: %p | Value: %s\n", &result, result);
        }
    }

    FreeLibraryAndExitThread((HMODULE) param, NULL);
    return NULL;
}
```

Yes, it works, but I noticed that I didn't understand one thing
How I can print address of that string using "result" variable, and does result needs to be pointer ?

Also in ReadProcessMemory parameters, why is there

```
(void*) ( ( char )
```

?

And is there way to memory address value of any data type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "result" is a pointer to a string, you can view the address and the string with this call:

```
printf("Address: %p | Value: %s\n", result, result);
```